# Control child process making

Tags: linux, bash

How to return the control to the parent process in the bash scripting when you are in the child process?

```
#/bin/bash
global_i=0
global_j=0
while((i<100))
do
    (
    while((j<100))
    do
        mkdir "shiv$i$j"
        let j=j+1
    done
    )
    echo shiv
    let i=i+1
done
```

Every thing working fine but the echo command is not running, which means that control is not coming back to the parent process.. Moreover, there is pid of only two processes: one is parent process and other is child process... but I want 100 child processes.

In C language, we can do it easily with fork functions — how to do it in bash scripting?

Comment: Are you planning to run 100 child processes simultaneously? That's quite a dangerous task and not IO friendly. Also it seems actually that you're trying to run 100 * 100 tasks.

Comment: I think the OP wants the second while loop to be in another process. to OP: it's as simple as adding `&` at the end of your second while loop: `(while ((j<100)) ... ) &` It's the ampersand symbol that creates a child process, not the parentheses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i just forgot to type & which makes child process

the code should be

```
#/bin/bash
global_i=0
global_j=0
while((i<100))
do
(
while((j<100))
do
mkdir "shiv$i$j"
let j=j+1
done
)&
echo shiv
let i=i+1
done
```

Comment: by the way i just edited..backquotes do nothing but run the code on terminal and subsitute the output.. hence it is mkdir so it does not cause any harm